# Error on Karaf (Predix 14.3) - 413 FULL head - 413 (Request Entity Too Large)

Tags: angularjs, playframework, playframework-2.1, apache-karaf, predix

I have the following architecture

**BROWSER <-> Play Framework 2.2.1 + AngularJS <-(REST)-> Karaf**

and it works; when I introduce

**BROWSER <-> Apache Revere Proxy <->Play Framework 2.2.1 + AngularJS <-(REST)-> Karaf**

it works; when I add OpenID authentication

**BROWSER <-> Apache Revere Proxy + OpenId Module <->Play Framework 2.2.1 + AngularJS <-(REST)-> Karaf**

I get on the browser

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 413
>   (Request Entity Too Large)

on the play framework log

> Request DefaultHttpRequest(chunked: false) GET
>   /service/connectc/command/prototypes/null HTTP/1.1 Host:
>   URLXXXXXXXXX:9090 uid: XXXXXXXX
>   ge_gessocompanyname: Company sm_first_name: Giacomo
>   Cookie:......
>
> Response DefaultHttpResponse(chunked: false) HTTP/1.1 413 FULL head
>   Content-Length: 0 Connection: close Server: Jetty(7.6.8.v20121106)

XXXXXX=url and my id name

Indeed **the authentication module introduce a very big header with Authentication token, SAML, Cookies etc...information**

any suggestion?

UPDATE: it seems an error of Karaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue enabling HTTPS protocol on KARAF; indeed the HTTP header is too small to host authentication (SAML) header.